# How can I replace the value to the above value in dataframe?

Tags: python

There is a dataframe as below:

```
| Name  Korean  English  Math highschool|
|0   YB     100      100   100      A|
|1   SW      90       90    90      B|
|2   EJ      80       80    80      C|
|3   EJ      70       70    70      D|
```

I would like to change the highschool value ("D") to the above value ("C") if the Name ("EJ") is same.

```
|Name  Korean  English  Math highschool|
|0   YB     100      100   100      A|
|1   SW      90       90    90      B|
|2   EJ      80       80    80      C|
|3   EJ      70       70    70      C|
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How is the dataframe represented in actual Python code? Is it a multi-line string?

Comment: Hi, did you already tried something? This is not a coding service :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are other values in the `Name` column that do repeat, you can use this method to replace all of the `highschool` values at once:

```
df1 = df.groupby("Name")["highschool"].first()
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
df.update(df1)
df.reset_index()
```

Replace `df` with the name of your dataframe.